# How can I display a parsed JSON (using liquid template) in a html table?

Tags: html, json, liquid, power-platform

I have this Dataverse table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdYaD.png)
where column cr68a_formulacomponents data is a JSON string.
I need to display this table in a Power Pages (Power Apps Portals), and I'd like this table to be expandable so when I click the row it'll show all the components of the selected formula. But here is how it's been shown to me:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MBj0.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPjTE.png)

I don't know how to solve this, the html/liquid code I'm using is:

```
<div id="ij4gqd" class="row sectionBlockLayout text-left" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; margin: 0px; min-height: auto; padding: 8px;">
  <div class="container" id="i3y9lx" style="padding: 0px; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
    <div class="col-md-12 columnBlockLayout" style="flex-grow: 1; display: flex; flex-direction: column; min-width: 250px; word-break: break-word;">
      <p id="i4kces">Veja as fórmulas salvas abaixo.<br /><br />Clique na linha desejada para visualizar os componentes da fórmula.&nbsp;</p>
      <!--FetchXML for table Saved Formulas-->    
      {% fetchxml savedFormulas %}
      <fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
        <entity name="cr68a_calculadoradevegetalizacaosavedformulas">
          <attribute name="cr68a_formulaid"/>
          <attribute name="cr68a_calculadoradevegetalizacaosavedformulasid"/>
          <attribute name="cr68a_formulaname" />
          <attribute name="cr68a_formulacomponents" />
          <attribute name="cr68a_formularesult" />
          <attribute name="createdon"/>
          <order attribute="createdon" descending="false" />
        </entity>
      </fetch>
    {% endfetchxml %}
<!--Display info for table Saved Formulas-->
{% assign tableRecords = entities['cr68a_calculadoradevegetalizacaosavedformulas'] %}
    <table id="tblSavedFormulas" class="fold-table" style="border:1px solid">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr class="table-heading">
          <th>Criado em</th>
          <th colspan="2">Nome da Fórmula</th>
          <th colspan="2">Índice de Vegetalização %</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {% for result in savedFormulas.results.entities %}
      {% assign columnids  = result.cr68a_calculadoradevegetalizacaosavedformulasid %}
        <tr id="allFormulas" class="view">
          <td id="txtCreatedOn">{{ result["createdon"]}}</td>
          <td id="txtFormulaName" colspan="2">{{ result["cr68a_formulaname"] }}</td>
          <td id="txtIndVegFormula" colspan="2">{{ result["cr68a_formularesult"]}}</td>   
        </tr>
        <tr id="headerComponents" class="fold">
          <td colspan="5">
            <div class="fold-content">
              <h6 style="text-align: center;">Componentes desta fórmula:</h6>
              {% assign jsonData = result["cr68a_formulacomponents"] %}
              {% assign parsedData = jsonData | json %}
              <table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Produto BASF?</th>
                    <th>Descrição Química</th>
                    <th>Marca BASF</th>
                    <th>Índice de Vegetalização</th>
                    <th>Concentração de Uso</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {% for item in parsedData %}
                  <tr>
                  <td colspan="1">{{ item.produtoBASF }}</td>
                  <td colspan="1">{{ item.descQuimica }}</td>
                  <td colspan="1">{{ item.marcaBASF }}</td>
                  <td colspan="1">{{ item.indiceVeg  }}</td>
                  <td colspan="1">{{ item.concentDeUso }}</td>
                  </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Can someone please help me with that? I'm new to Liquid template